# How to see webpage speed in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer

What's the best way to see a webpage's speed in IE7+?

For Firefox, there's the [Lori](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1743) (Life-of-request info) plugin, that gives time to first byte, time to completion, file size and number of requests, all in the bottom of the browser window.

The closest I can think of is fiddler, but that gives a lot more info than I'm looking for and is somewhere extra to look. What other tools are there?

Comment: I find that time-lapse photography works the best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HI

**HTTPWatch** is another tool which resembles fiddler..   there are 2 versions available [**professional and basic**](http://www.httpwatch.com/download/)

i think basic edition may fit your needs.

**Update:**

I just came across a interesting post by [john resig - deep tracing IE](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/) about the new client side profiler tool for IE. It is awsome & Its free.

You can get it [here](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/download/download.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use http://www.webpagetest.org/test

I know it's not the ideal solution, but I don't know any plugin for this.

Comment: Would only work on sites in the "real world", nothing running locally or internally.

Comment: In all fairness, you didn't specify this!

Answer (score 1):

Check [Fiddler web debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which will give you what you are looking for and more.

Comment: Is there a way to see fiddler results inside IE i'm missing? Fiddler gives me too much info and I can't get to the value I'm interested in quickly. See OP.

Comment: yes, i know i just said fiddler as a reference, but i know it contains too much details, but personally i like it too much for simple and complex uses.

Comment: You want to use the neXpert addon for Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/addons/nexpert.asp.  It will generate a report for you summarizing your performance and provide tips for faster pages.

Comment: Furthermore, if you simply select all of the sessions and look at the "Statistics" tab, at the top, you'll find exactly the info you requested... session count, size, and timings.